# How to add a tooltip to the legend in google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Using the newest version of the Google Charts API.

I have a simple bar chart and I would like to show a tooltip when hovering over the elements in the legend which explain what each item in the legend is. I would still like the tooltip on the bars to stay the same and display its labels and values.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population',],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Total Population',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'City'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

     </script>
    </head> 
  <body>
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above chart, how would you add a tooltip to the 2010 population legend element when you hover over it that says "Data taken from 2010 US Census"?

**UPDATE**

After figuring out the answer I've made a codepen to show how you can make each element in the legend show different descriptions. I hope this helps someone in the future.

https://codepen.io/jonnyske7ch/pen/bWzmxW

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population', '2011 Population'],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 3792000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 1526000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 8175000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 2695000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 2099000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var legendTooltip = document.getElementById('legend-tooltip');

  // set legend tooltip position
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function (gglEvent) {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var legendBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('legend');
    legendTooltip.style.top = (legendBounds.top + (legendBounds.height * 2)) + 'px';
    legendTooltip.style.left = legendBounds.left + 'px';
  });

  // show legend tooltip
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (gglEvent) {
    if (gglEvent.row === null) {
   if (data.getColumnLabel(gglEvent.column) === '2010 Population') {
    $('#series-name').html(data.getColumnLabel(gglEvent.column) + ' - Data from 2010 Census');
   } else if (data.getColumnLabel(gglEvent.column) === '2011 Population') {
    $('#series-name').html(data.getColumnLabel(gglEvent.column) + ' - Data from 2011 Census');
   }
      $(legendTooltip).removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });

  // hide legend tooltip
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function (gglEvent) {
    if (gglEvent.row === null) {
      $(legendTooltip).addClass('hidden');
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ggl-tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="legend-tooltip" class="ggl-tooltip hidden">
  <div id="series-name"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no standard tooltip for legend entries, but you can add your own...

see following working snippet,

here, i use chart events `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`,
to know when the legend has been "hovered"

when the events fire, if the `row` property of the event is `null`,
then the legend is being hovered

i also use `getChartLayoutInterface` to position the tooltip near the legend

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population',],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var legendTooltip = document.getElementById('legend-tooltip');

  // set legend tooltip position
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function (gglEvent) {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var legendBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('legend');
    legendTooltip.style.top = (legendBounds.top + (legendBounds.height * 2)) + 'px';
    legendTooltip.style.left = legendBounds.left + 'px';
  });

  // show legend tooltip
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (gglEvent) {
    if (gglEvent.row === null) {
      $('#series-name').html(data.getColumnLabel(gglEvent.column));
      $(legendTooltip).removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });

  // hide legend tooltip
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function (gglEvent) {
    if (gglEvent.row === null) {
      $(legendTooltip).addClass('hidden');
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ggl-tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="legend-tooltip" class="ggl-tooltip hidden">
  <div><span>Series Info</span></div>
  <div id="series-name"></div>
</div>
```