# How to add tooltip in the vaxis labels/ticks in the google scatter chart?

Tags: angular, google-visualization, tooltip

i already checked the documentation but it is not in there. A simple code and solution to my problem will be a great help. The goal is to add tooltip in each device label. Click this link. [Device Scatter Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7mVJ.png)

**Update 05/16/19**

One solution is to create SVGTitleElement and append it to the SVGText element.

```
addTooltip(){
    var texts = document.getElementsByTagName("text");
    for(var index = 0; index < texts.length; index++){
      var innerTag = texts.item(index);
      if(this.vAxisLabels.indexOf(innerTag.innerHTML) >= 0){
        var newTitle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title");
        newTitle.innerHTML = innerTag.innerHTML;
        innerTag.appendChild(newTitle);
      }
    }
  }
```

Other useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42745584/10214587

Comment: not possible out of the box, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143882/5090771) of adding a custom tooltip for the legend, it may get you close...

Comment: @WhiteHat This is useful. I want to upvote your comment but not enough rep point. Thank you!

Comment: @WhiteHat, thanks for your help! i already have a solution.